# IOS/Objective-C/Core Data: NSPredicates with Complicated Conditional logic

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I am using an NSPredicate to filter an entity in coredata.  Most of the examples Apple and others provides do not embody the complicated logic you can do in SQL but since the predicates resolve to sql, it seemed to me there might be more that is possible than is readily viewable in the apple docs.

In particular, I would like to filter managed objects by one date if a certain attribute is true but an earilier date, if the attribute is false.

Something like:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *lastYear =   [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitYear value:-1 toDate:now options:0];

NSPredicate *myPred=  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"new==1 ? date >= %@ :date>=%@", now,lastYear];
```

Is there any way to put conditional logic inside an NSPredicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be achievable with following format

```
@"(new == 1 AND date >= %@) OR (new == 0 AND date >= %@)", now, lastYear
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Also, in https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html you can find documentation for NSPredicate syntax

Comment: Looks so easy after the fact.  Very dense of me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(new == 1 AND date >= %@) OR (new == 0 AND date >= %@)", now, lastYear];
```

Comment: Could you please explain how your answer is different from @johnyu's answer? He already answered the same thing aprx 4 hours before than you.